# Rolling 12 dice, what's the probability of having 2 dice for each number

Tags: probability

Rolling 12 dice, what's the probability of having 2 dice for each number? (so you got two 1, two 2, two 3... two 6)? In answer from the book as below.

My question is $\frac{12!}{2^6}$shows the number of subsets we have in total when evenly distribute 12 dice into 6 groups, why don't we need to times 6!? we pick 2 dice first, then choose one number out of six, we then pick 2 other dice, then choose one number out of five...?Why don't we consider after splitting 12 dice into 6 groups, we also need to order the if each group get which number in 1-6?

[image]

Comment: *dice* is plural; *die* is singular

Comment: The [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) $\dfrac{12!}{2^6}=\binom{12}{2,2,2,2,2,2}$ is the number of ways to partition $12$ objects into six **labeled** groups.  We don't need to multiply by $6!$ because the groups are already labeled as being intended for the dice who show 1 versus the dice who show 2 versus the dice who show 3, etc...

Comment: If you insist, then you can find the number of ways of having the twelve dice split into *unlabeled* groups as $11!! = 11\cdot 9\cdot 7\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 1$ and then multiply this result by $6!$ to assign a label (*number*) to each group... you'll find that $11!!\cdot 6! = \dfrac{12!}{2^6}$, giving the same final result as above.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks, do you mind help me understand why the multinomial coefficient is "labeled"? and why the "unlabled" is 11!!? mind put in the answer so that i will accept/upvote. thx

Comment: $\binom{12}{2,2,2,2,2,2}=\binom{12}{2}\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\cdots\binom{2}{2}$ is the number of ways to choose two of the twelve positions to be for the number $1$, then choose two of the ten remaining positions to be for the number $2$, and so on...  For unlabeled, the first die will be in some unknown group.  We pick which of the remaining $11$ dice gets paired with the first.  From those dice remaining, the leftmost remaining will be in some group, we pick which of the remaining $9$ dice gets paired with this, and so on...